# Why does it print only one time? Please give me solution

Tags: javascript, html

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function printpage()
        {document. getElementById ('print').style.display='none';
        window.print()
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <td align="center">
    <input  name="print" type="submit" id="print" value="PRINT" onclick="printpage()" />
  </td>
</body>
</html>
```

When I click, it will open a print window.
Once I close print window and open it again and then click on print, without reloading, then it will not work.

Comment: What is it that you're trying to attain?

Comment: Please take the time to format your code and properly space it. We should not have to labour to read your code. If you can't be bothered to even put line breaks in, why should anyone help?

Comment: Wondering how you clicked on the print button again if it was hidden?

Comment: First, there is no PHP involved in this isse (wrong tag). Second, as Ashwin said, how did you click the print button a second time since it is being hidden after the frist click? Did you mean that you can't find the button after you clicked it? That's because it's hidden. Solution: add `document.getElementById('print').style.display='block';` after `window.print();`

Comment: @user1500506: see my answer having solution with css media queries.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove `document.getElementById('print').style.display='none';` from your `printpage()` function.

In the above case the button will be visible for another click event but when you will print the document, the button will be shown on printed document. Am I right?

To prevent printing the `print` button you need to use [css media queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/) `@media print`

**Add following in your extrernal stylesheet OR in `<style>` tag inside a `<head>` tag of the HTML page:**

```
 @media print {    
     .noprint { display: none; }
 }​
```

and add `.noprint` class on

```
<input  name="print" class="noprint" type="submit" id="print" value="PRINT" onclick="printpage()" />
```

[**SEE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/akhurshid/wR76u/)

It will print the document without printing the button and your button will also be visible for the second time click :-)

**EDITED:**

**USE HTML AS GIVEN BELOW:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

      <meta charset=utf-8 />  
      <title>JS Bin</title>  

      <!-- Your Stylesheet (CSS) -->  
      <style type="text/css">
         @media print {    
           .noprint { display: none; }
         }​
      </style>

      <!-- Your Javascript Function -->  
      <script>
          function printpage() {       
              window.print();
          }
      </script>

    </head>
<body>

<!-- Your Body -->
<p>Only This text will print</p>

<!-- Your Button -->
<input class="noprint" type="button" value="PRINT" onclick="printpage()" />

</body>
</html>
```

[**SEE ABOVE CODE IN ACTION**](http://jsbin.com/otihov/1/edit)

Comment: @M2K: what you have tried? create a fiddle on jsfiddle.net or jsbin.com

Comment: @M2K: I have updated my answer with an HTML code, just copy paste the html in a blank html document, ant try. It will definitely work.

Answer (score 1):

Change type=submit to type=button

You are unloading the page when submitting

And hide the button with CSS as posted by [A.K.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11738592/295783)

Comment: You are not giving enough information, someone already asked: how could you print again when you button disappeared. So tell us exactly what you do step by step and if there are other scripts on the page. Even better: give use the URL of a test page

Answer (score 0):

Just remove

```
document.getElementById('print').style.display='none';
```

from your `printpage()` function. It'll work fine

If you don't want the print button on your printed page,

```
document.getElementById('print').style.visibility='hidden'
window.print();
document.getElementById('print').style.visibility='visible'
```

Comment: This will lead to the print button being printed, too.

Comment: @MiDo Ya i know, but he wants to print it again . And if he doesn't want to see that button, your solution suits best

Comment: +1. It might be best to create a stylesheet for printing that doesn't show the button.