# How to prevent printing the ::after css?

Tags: html, css, media-queries, pseudo-element

I am trying to print my webpage but the problem is the thing `::after` in css is always shown in print view I tried to follow the

```
@media print{
    .noprint{
        display:none;
    }
}
```

procedure in CSS from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17964834/how-to-print-some-specific-part-of-a-page-via-window-print)

Update:
Here is my code in CSS

```
@media print{
#submenu,#submenu:after,#add,#view,#del,#edit,#menu_content,#menu{display:none;}
}//should i put double':'?
```

Here it is[image: some part of page]

Comment: I have never tried but doesnt `.noprint::after{display: none;}` not work?

Comment: More importantly, what is generating the `::after`? If the one generating it is not marked `.noprint`, then there is no reason the pseudo-element should be prevented from printing.

Comment: I don't see any `::after` rules in the code that you posted; can you post more complete css code?

Comment: not working @harry .noprint, it is some of my class

Comment: `@media print{ *::after { display:none !important; } }`

Comment: question updated @ErwinBolwidt both ':' and '::' is not working

Comment: i fixed it, thanks for the time. i should put `!important`

Comment: @CristalynDuena: Good that you found a solution but adding `!important` is never a good practice mate. Though it fixed your case, maybe changing the ordering of your CSS or the specificity of your selectors could be a better way around. If you could post a demo sample (HTML + CSS) then some of us here could help.

Comment: @Harry, I'm a big `!important` opponent 99% of the time, but to be fair this seems like a valid use. How else are you going to override specificity no matter what selector was used before the `::after`? How much damage can it do? Reset/override styles with such importance warrant the use imo.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by Mark Nijboer in the comments, the following rule would work:

```
@media print {
    *::after {
        display: none !important;
    }
}
```

Another way to do it would be:

```
@media print {    
    *noprint::after {
        content: '' !important;
    }
}
```

A pseudo-element without content is not shown by any browser.

If you're adamant do doing it without using `!important`, you will either have to make the rule overly specific to make sure you override all other selectors, or you can try and find a property that you're sure isn't used by any of the pseudo-elements.